# javascript object push how to set key value

Tags: javascript, object, push

Is there any way to set own key value when using javascript push method? Here is my example:

```
  <script>
  var examples = [];
  </script>  

  <?php foreach($examples as $example):?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var example<?php echo $example['id']?> = { 
    id : '<?php echo $example['id']?>',
    another : '<?php echo $example['another']?>',
  };
  //here I would like to give key $example[id]
  examples.push(example<?php echo $example['id']?>);
  </script>  
  <?php endforeach;?>

  <script>  
    for (index = 0; index < examples.length; ++index) {
        somefunction(examples[index]);  
    }                            
  </script>
```

For some reasons I need $example['id'] to have the same value as pushed key.

Comment: Why don't you just write (for the entire thing): `var examples = <?php echo json_encode($examples) ?>;` ?

Comment: I think I will try also that. I don't know why I haven't tried it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making an array is making this a bit harder than you need it to be if you need the IDs to match.

If you want to reference it by the ID, you can simply use a vanilla JS object

```
<script>
var examples = {};
</script>  

<?php foreach($examples as $example):?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var example<?php echo $example['id']?> = { 
  id : '<?php echo $example['id']?>',
  another : '<?php echo $example['another']?>',
};
//here I would like to give key $example[id]
examples['' + <?php echo $example['id']?>] = example;
</script>  
<?php endforeach;?>

<script>  
  for (var k in examples) {
      somefunction(examples[k]);  
  }                            
</script>
```

This will let you set arbitrary string keys and loop through just like an array.

Comment: Tnx, that is what I need. Just one correction to the answer: Inside for this should also go _if (!examples.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue_

Answer (score 1):

Use an object instead:

```
var examples = {};
...
examples[key] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your id is a string value, then you need a mapping object (var obj = {}; obj[key] = value), but you wan't be able to use it as an array since it's not an array, though, you still can do something like this: for (var k in elements) { if (elements.hasOwnProperty(k)) {do something} }

If you really want to use an Array than you can try using splice ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice ) method to insert your elements at certain index (just make sure that array length is always greater than index value you are trying to insert at), but for that your id has to be numeric, not a stirng.